# sale price de woocommerce tenga cualquier valor y que no sea menor al regular price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-plugin

Quiero cambiar el valor de "sale price" de los productos para que no me dé un error al ponerlo mayor que el "Regular price", ¿cómo podría hacer esto? ¿utilizando PHP en el código del woocommerce o instalando un plugin?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado buscando en el código del plugins y éste es el que tengo en function.php:

```
function bd_rrp_sale_price_html( $price, $product ) {

if ( $product->is_on_sale() ) :
$has_sale_text = array(
'<del>' => '<del><span class="arprice">MSRP:</span>',
'<ins>' => '<ins><span class="arprice"> Our Price : </span>'
);
$return_string .= str_replace(array_keys( $has_sale_text ), array_values( $has_sale_text ), $price);

else :
$retun_string = $price;
endif;

$return_string.='<span class="arprice hh">PRE-OWNED : Call For Quote </span>';

return $return_string;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'bd_rrp_sale_price_html', 100, 2 );
```

También estoy buscando en el código del plugin woocommerce para encontrar la variable desde ahí.

Comment: No conozco de woocomerce ... pero conozco de compra venta de cosas.

Y no es lógico que tu saleprice (precio de oferta) sea mayor a tu regularprice... O sea, es una oferta, no puede ser mas alto que el precio normal

Comment: FederHico estoy de acuerdo, pero es algo que me pidieron y como desarrollador web quiero investigar todo lo posible para lograrlo, yo también me quede pensativo cuando me dijeron, pero no creo que sea imposible .

Comment: pues, buena suerte, desconozco, no puedo ayudarte en lo técnico

Answer (score 1):

Sin tener que modificar el código del plugin, directamente yo creería que puede modificar el precio de los productos por base de datos. No es una práctica recomendada, pero es una solución temporal

```sql
UPDATE wp_postmeta AS s
SET s.meta_value = 'el valor que usted quiera'
WHERE s.meta_key = '_sale_price'
AND s.post_id = 'el id que ud encontró'
```

La tabla `wp_postmeta` es la que contiene los precios de los productos creados en woocommerce.

`meta_key` es la columna que posee el campo `'_sale_price'` y `meta_value` es quien posee el valor del sale price.

Sólo requiere conocer el id del producto que quiere actualizar y luego ejecutar la query sobre la base de datos relacionada al woocommerce.